# Jenkins DeleteDir() function : Unable to delete

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the function DeleteDir() in my script. Sometimes, the error : Unable to delete... appears, but I can go to the directory and delete it myself. It seems to happen randomly... Someone knows why ?
Thx.

Comment: Could something else have a hold of the directory or a file it contains? Does it give you any error?

Comment: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed.. and java.io.IOException: Unable to delete.. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.

Comment: Oooph. Yeah, so something probably is holding onto it, getting in your way. The trick will be finding out which process is doing that.

Comment: I'll search , thx :)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I am running into the same problem.

Comment: No , I've removed all of my DeleteDir() ...

Answer (score 0):

check the functional id's permission to the folder. If there is no enough permission to the functional id then the process will not be able to delete the folder.